# How to organize a key/legend into catagories for ggplot

Tags: r, sorting, ggplot2, graphics, key

I've been working on a massive scooby-doo spreadsheet project and it is coming along well. Everything but the key. I've been wanting to make the key into somewhat of a table to where each characters' voice actors are sorted (i.e. a head that says Velma's voice actors and under it Marla Scott, Nicole Jaffe and Pat Stevens and same for the other 4). But so far it is only sorted by quantity of each of the voice actors. I'm not sure if r is able to do this and if not I'll simply edit a table in but still want to see if you can.

```
scooby %>% ggplot(aes(x = 1, y = series.name, col = fred.va, size = run.time, alpha = .9)) +
  geom_jitter(width = .4, height = .35) +
  geom_jitter(aes(col = daphnie.va, x = 2), width = .4, height = .35) +
  geom_jitter(aes(col = velma.va, x = 3), width = .4, height = .35) +
  geom_jitter(aes(col = shaggy.va, x = 4), width = .4, height = .35) +
  geom_jitter(aes(col = scooby.va, x = 5), width = .4, height = .35) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "brown", "#1b39ce", "purple", "#fd5f00",
                                "orange", "grey", "#ffd938", "#ff53aa")) +
  labs(title = "Voice Actor by Series", color = "") + xlab("Voice Actors") + ylab("Series Name")
```

[image: here is the product so far:]

many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `ggnewscale` for that, after you define an additional column for grouping certain voice actors.

Here is a simple example splitting a variable into subgroups and adding separate legends:

```r
invisible(suppressPackageStartupMessages(
    lapply(c("ggnewscale","dplyr","ggplot2", "reshape2", "Hmisc"),
           require, character.only=TRUE)))
data("iris")

# define some groups
iris$clr <- cut2(iris$Sepal.Length, g=9)

# define some subgroups
iris$Group <- case_when(
    iris$clr %in% levels(iris$clr)[1:3] ~ "low",
    iris$clr %in% levels(iris$clr)[4:6] ~ "medium",
    iris$clr %in% levels(iris$clr)[7:9] ~ "high") %>% factor(., unique(.))

ggplot(filter(iris, Group=="low"), aes(x=1, y=Species, size=Sepal.Width, col=clr)) + 
    geom_jitter(width = .4, height = .35) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "brown", "#1b39ce"), name = "low", guide = guide_legend(order = 3)) +
    new_scale_color() +
    geom_jitter(data=filter(iris, Group=="medium"), inherit.aes=FALSE, aes(x=1, y=Species, col=clr, size=Petal.Length), width = .4, height = .35) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("purple", "#fd5f00", "orange"), name = "medium", guide = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
    new_scale_color() +
    geom_jitter(data=filter(iris, Group=="high"), inherit.aes=FALSE, aes(x=1, y=Species, col=clr, size=Petal.Length), width = .4, height = .35) +
    scale_color_manual(values = c("grey", "#ffd938", "#ff53aa"), name = "high", guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) + 
    guides(size = guide_legend(order=1))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>